# How to implement user deposits for tokens for an exchange

Tags: tokens, erc-20, security, exchanges, erc-223

If we generate new deposit addresses for every user we face following problems:
- we need to transfer tokens from individual wallets to our exchange wallets
- we need to fund the wallets with ether to be able to pay gas for the transfer above

How do other exchanges solve this? If we say the users should all deposits to one address or smart contract we run in other usability issues and will need other mechanisms to connect deposits to users

Answer (score 4):

You can have a few shared addresses where you consolidate several transfers and have a single transfer instead. It can be complex to manage to which user the tokens have to be credited. A user can send tokens to a previous address without requesting authorization.

IMHO the easiest is to generate a custom address per user. You will have to pay the ether for the extra transfer but it should be covered by the fee the user have to pay when he wants to withdraw tokens.

In any case you probably want to consolidate all your tokens inside a cold wallet, and you will have to pay fees for that transfer.