# Crypto Exchange Account Model (HD Wallet?)

Tags: blockchain, addresses, private-key, public-key

There are some crypto networks such as Bitcoin, Ethereum, TRON, Solana, etc.
To develop a crypto exchange, it is a good idea to have a private key for each network, and generate an address (for deposit) for each customer, if possible. (If in the blockchain, we can sign a transaction or spend from multiple addresses, with a single private key)
If this feature is not available, an exchange has to create a unique pair of public-private key for every customer. It means that the receiving funds are split into several accounts that spending them is hard and may require many small transactions and fees.

If I am right, how can I check that a network has this feature?

Comment: You can read here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6520/can-i-use-the-same-private-key-for-ethereum-and-bitcoin Sometimes you can use the same private key for two networks but you should notice that generating keys and accounts might help to manage funds and for anonymity. **Note:** An account address is generated using the private key, so, for each private key there is a unique address.

Comment: Similar questions were asked in the past https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82479/how-do-exchanges-work-internally, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43206/how-to-implement-user-deposits-for-tokens-for-an-exchange, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84401/how-to-build-an-ethereum-hot-wallet-for-an-exchange, etc. There's no unique solution, each exchange adapts to their needs and security requirements.